# How to session Expire in UIWebview in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, session, swift3, webview, uiwebview

i want to logout from the webview after logged in uiwebview but some Sites Provides Logout Button to Logout ,

and Some Website Or Blogs have not Logout button So i want To switch User With Same Device And Same Webview Without Delete App.

So Any Idea About To Clear Session Or Expire Session From WebView. Because M using UiWebview

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clear the cashed data in the web view:

```
func clearCookies()
{
    if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies
    {
        URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
        URLCache.shared.diskCapacity = 0
        URLCache.shared.memoryCapacity = 0
        for cookie in cookies
        {
            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.deleteCookie(cookie)
        }
    }
}
```